# Cooked pork left out overnight

Tags: pork

I left cooked pork out overnight. Will this present a danger? Since this morning when we realized it was out still, we have been refrigerating it ever since. Also we wonder if when reheating the meat if we heat it very well will that help kill any existing bacteria?

Answer (score 0):

In these sort of circumstances, as the cooked pork would have been left out for an extended period of time, it would be safer to throw the meat out. Even if no visible mould is showing. The meat would have been sitting in the correct thermal conditions for bacteria to begin growing, which is 4-60 Celsius.

Although it is common to hear that re-heating will kill the bacteria, the produce of the bacteria, i.e. protein toxins, cannot be killed off and can cause damage to your health if ingested. It is better to be safe than sorry in situations such as these.